# SVN Tagging practice for paper documents

Tags: svn, version-control, tagging

I administrate an SVN system in a manufacturer of engine parts. Previously they had no means of version control / poor file history tracking on their documents, and while SVN is an unconventional solution in our context, I've developed a workflow that fits our development model for producing engineering documents. The only thing I can't quite place is tagging, but I'll back up a bit and briefly summarize the workflow..

1. **Repositories** are made named after the **part number**.
2. A **branch** is made of the trunk named after the **job number**, to track changes to files that may only apply specifically to that order of parts. If the changes to the manufacturing process work and will be used on future processes, they are merged back into the **trunk**.

In this sense / in other words, the trunk is a *template* or *master file* for jobs, and gets updated from the *development branch* when the branch's efficiency *supersedes the template*. (i.e., using looser tolerances, changing tools or material, or changes in design)

**Here's the stick:** 3. For document control - tracking what documents get **released** to the manufacturing floor - *tags* are made from the branch, so we know exactly what papers are in our machinist's hands without having to walk out there and ask questions and check dates, and be able to review the job later on.

The problem I have is controlling when *the released documents take on changes after the first tag / release*. This can happen for a number of reasons from problems on the floor that may come up. I'll commit new changes to the branch, and then I have to get the drawings signed and **released again**.

**What would be the best way to handle this to avoid confusion?**

- Merge from the job branch into the previously released tag?
- Make a new tag?

  - If so, what should the naming convention be? This isn't software, so language such as "Version 2.0" or something along those lines doesn't really fit, *revision* would in this field, but that's obviously already conflicting with other terminology.

[image: Here's a snapshot of what I'm talking about if it helps.]

(646C574 is the part number, seen in the URL of the repo)  I'm stumped as to what would look professional & clear to understand. I can't use a convention like 202040-2, 202040-C, as those are also valid job numbers in the system (components of assemblies).

If anyone has an idea of something that'd fit the bill, that'd be swell. I'm still trying to sell the whole SVN workflow to upper management and giving our digital documents integrity like this is a very big deal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just use some separator that's not already used in your system and an incrementor.  I'd probably use `#` since you can tell people to read it as revision #n.  I.E. `202040#1` would be your first tag, `202040#2` would be your second and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions:

- Use release date as mandatory trailing part of tag-name (you can get date from `svn ls`, but using in name make life slightly easier) - i.e your tag will be like "202040-2014-01-20", next will be in "202040-2014-MM-DD" pattern
- Don't commit to tags (and using trunk|branches|tags naming) is *only convention*, you can (in your specific workflow and with your needs) don't follow it and commit every new **released version** of specification into the same node in /tags and history of releases will be `svn log ^/tags/202040/`